# Invoking Get-Process remotely with a script block

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get process information of a process using powershell.

So, I have something like this

```
$command = {  Get-Process -Name process* }
$res = Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock $command
Remove-PSSession $session
Write-Host $res
```

My output is

```
System.Diagnostics.Process (process)
```

When I login to the box and run Get-Process -Name process I get much more information such as Handles, NPM, PK, CPU, etc...

How can I get the same information using Invoke-Command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$res` is not a string object, so using write-host with it will not display the data that the object contains.  Remove `write-host` from the last line so it will just be:

```
$res
```

...and PowerShell is smart enough to know how to display the data that's in the object.

Answer (score 2):

Unless this is a *very* simplified version of what you really need to do, there's no need to involve the additional overhead of a separate `PSSession` and `Invoke-Command` here. `Get-Process` takes `ComputerName` as a parameter and will return the collection of `System.Diagnostics.Process` objects directly.